# Passing new data to a Job everytime it runs - Quartz

Tags: java, process, queue, quartz-scheduler, scheduling

I have two jobs running. First job polls data and updates the queue. Another one reads the queue and processes it. I need to pass fresh data to second job every time it runs. Second jobs runs every 10 seconds. So I need to pass fresh JobDataMap every time the 2nd job runs.

I read Quartz documentation on this one. But its not clear. Should I use one JobDataMap and pass it back and forth filling it up? Or is there a way to create new JobDataMap and pass it to job every time the job runs.

Any idea?

Comment: Why not use an external singleton service to achieve this ? Instead of passing argument through JobDataMap.